# Parametro no Register laravel

Tags: php, laravel, framework

Gostaria de saber se é possivel passar um parametro por url no `auth` padrão do `Laravel`, aquele que se faz por `make:auth`

```
register/login
```

pois esse login iria utilizar na tabela `user`?

Comment: Qual o motivo que você precisa parar um valor na url?

Comment: é como fosse um registrar com indicacao

Comment: Na minha opinião pela experiência se poderia fazer o seu próprio método de autenticação com a classe `User` e usar ai um regra especifica. A que é criada é muito engessada!

Comment: vlw Virgilio, eu rescrevi uma parte do codigo la no frame msm pra receber o login